# How to convert a String to an InputStream in Kotlin?

Tags: arrays, string, kotlin, inputstream

I have a string:

```
var myString:String  = "My String"
```

How can I convert it to an `InputStream` in Kotlin?

Comment: I am baffled by the idea that this question could possibly need more focus.  It is clearly about one thing.  The one-line-of-code answer makes that even clearer.  I am voting to reopen.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Kotlin has an extension for `String` to convert directly.

```
val inputStream: InputStream = myString.byteInputStream()
```

The argument on `byteInputStream` is defaulted to `charset: Charset = Charsets.UTF_8`.

You can look at the extension by writing it and then cmd+click on it or in the `package kotlin.io` file `IOStream.kt`

Relying on the Java version is not wrong, but rather using a more kotlin idiomatic way when possible

Answer (score 0):

```
val myString = "text"
val targetStream: InputStream = ByteArrayInputStream(initialString.toByteArray())
```

Pst.
If you copy some java code, for example:

```
String myString = "text";
InputStream targetStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(myString.getBytes());
```

Android Studio will popup "Clipboard content seems to be Java code. Do you want to convert it to Kotlin?